# Django Combine two templated from different apps

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have two apps with the following structure

```
project->
    main app->
       templates->
           dashboard.html
    my app->
       templates->
           mydashboard.html
```

I want to include `mydashboard` into `dashboard`, well this is possible using include template tag. but my problem appears when I have to pass some parameters into `mydashboard`, let's say they are named `param1` and `param2` these parameters are the variables which I have to load from `my app` app. well one possible method is to filling these params in dashboardview in `mainapp` and pass them using `include` tag into `mydashboard.html` like below

```
def user_dashboard(request):
  ...-->here I have to get data from my app (this view is in main app and I do not want to make main app be dependent to my app
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'param1': 0, 'param2': 34})
```

then in   `dashboard.html` I add this part

```
{% is_app_installed "myapp" as is_myapp_installed %}
           {% if is_myapp_installed %}
                {% include "myappdashboard.html" with param1=param1 param2=param2 %}
           {% endif %}
```

It seems the above method works but the main problem is that using this method `mainapp` is dependent to `myapp` and I do not want to this happens.
is there any other method to load those param1 and param2 inside `myapp`?
thanks

Comment: The only way I can figure would be to have an API in myapp that allows javascript to fetch the data from inside your myappdashboard template

Comment: Its already dependent on the `my app`, since you are using the template from other app.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the details of the templates, but if you want to decouple the two templates I suggest you to rethink how you organise your templates logic. Try to rearrange the logic adding a `base_dashboard.html` in a common template dir with snippets and base templates to share between the apps.

Then the `myappdashboard.html` and `dashboard.html` can extend it with `{% extend base_dashboard.html %}`.